# Why all items always go to enter and exit selections at the same time in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a problem with General Update Pattern in d3.js. Every time (even if the same data is coming) all my elements go to both `enter` and `exit` selections. `Update` is empty.

This is my function :

```
function render() {
  const test = svg
  .selectAll('.test')
  .data(data, d => d.name);

  console.log(test)

 const onEnter = test
 .enter()
 .append('text')
 .attr('class', 'test')
 .attr('x', 50)
 .attr('y', 100)
 .attr('fill', 'black')
 .datum(d => d.values)
 .text(d => {
  return d[0].value
 })
 .attr('y', (_, i) => 50 + 25 * i)
}
```

I discovered that the `datum` bind is the problem (without it everything works as expected), but I have no idea how to fix it and why it causes a problem. I need to use `datum`, the real case is much bigger.

You can test it on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kamil_p/wv6u7tab/16/). When you click `update` button you can see in console `enter` and `exit` selections with 2 elements, while I would expect 2 elements to be in `_groups` array.

Why binding `datum` causes that General Update Pattern works like that?

Comment: Don't call datum() in enter/exit pattern code. Datum() is intended to either retrieve the already entered data or bind data to individual elements that were not created with enter()